# Flutter FilterChip _cast list load dynamically from an endpoint

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using the Sample Code in the example found here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html

In the sample code, `_cast` is a `final` list.

To make the `_cast` list be populated by a list response from an endpoint, what changes need to be made?

What I've done?

I've tried using `FutureBuilder` but for whatever unknown reasons to me, the return of the `future` is not passed into `builder` as snapshot.

https://gist.github.com/seanmavley/0a5f5190272c4f1a60b5a47203a06746

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
List<ActorFilterEntry> _castList;
  loadInterest() async {
    ...
    setState(() {
      _castEntry = res['interest'];
    });
  }
```

Comment: I get error along the lines: `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.`